# How to run di basic example of WSO2 EI Business Process?

Tags: middleware, wso2, wso2-esb

I am absolutly new in **WSO2 EI** and I have the following doubt.

I am following this official tutorial to study the creation of a business process **BPMN process**):

https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Quick+Start+Guide

If you go in this tutorial the second tab is refered to the **Business Process Management** tutorial, then I continue following the business process **BPMN process** street.

I followed all the tutorial and I think that I have understand the key concept of this example but I have some doubts about how to run this example.

At the end of the tutorial it does:

> **To create the Business Archive File (.bar), do the following.**
>
> - On the Explorer, found in the upper left of your screen, navigate to **Package Explorer**.
> - Right click on the package and select **“Create deployment artifacts”**.
> - Navigate to the location of the source. You will find the **.bar** file inside the deployment folder.

So now I have my **/HelloWorld/deployment/OrderApproval.bar** file created.

But now what have I to do with this file?

I also have download the **EI Server** from here: /HelloWorld/deployment/OrderApproval.bar

Then I have configured it in my Eclipse Developer Studio EI setting it as a WSO2 server.

So my doubts are:

1. What exactly represent this **OrderApproval.bar** file? Is it a file representing a **WSO2 EI** executable project or what?
2. From what I have understand the previous example represents a work flow representing a **BPMN process** that implements a flow with some rules without that I need to write Java code (correct me if I am doing wrong assertion). But is it something executable or something that have to be integrated into some other application?
3. If it is an executable project what have I to do to run it and interact with it?

Answer (score 0):

BPMN is process definition that can be run on BPS server. BPS server is part of WSO2 EI solution. You have to run it from [EI_HOME]/wso2/business-process/bin
On Linux/Mac OS:  sh wso2server.sh
On Windows:  wso2server.bat --run

Then, when it works correctly, open https : // [serverIP]:[port]/carbon/  and log into the EI-Business Process management console.

Next navigate to Home -> Manage -> Processes ->Add -> BPMN and upload your OrderApproval.bar file.

After uploading file, log into the BPMN-explorer at https : // [serverIP]:[port]/bpmn-explorer. On the "proecesses" tab you should see your process which can be run by action->start.

Try studie this example: https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Creating+a+BPMN+Process